# Pass nothing into @binding property

Tags: swift, swiftui

I do not want to pass anything into binding property such as following code.
Is it possible?

```
struct ParentView: View {        
    var body: some View {
        ChildView()
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @Binding var prop: String? // may be passed by other parent view

    var body: some View {
        Text("Child View")
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `Binding.constant(nil)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution. Tested with Xcode 11.4.

```
struct ChildView: View {
    @Binding var prop: String? // may be passed by other parent view

    init(prop: Binding<String?> = .constant(nil)) {    // << here !!
        _prop = prop
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("Child View")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using the underscore when assigning _prop = prop?

Comment: @zumzum, `prop` is wrapped value, but with underscore `_prop` is wrapper (binding in this case) here by swift convention.